# How to put this symbol: " ' " (simple Quotation mark) in a XMLfile of android?

Tags: android, xml

i am translating some text into Italian, an i got an error on this line of the XML of the strings.xml because the ' symbol on L'utente:

```
<string name="usernotexist">L'utente non esiste</string>
```

how to solve that error?

Comment: What is the error message? I suspect an encoding issue, but it is hard to tell without more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<string name="dialog">L\'tutente non esiste </string>
```

Comment: The `\` character is not how you perform an escape in XML.

Comment: @David That's how it works on Android. Read the documentation before downvoting ;)

Comment: @Cristian Out of curiosity, doesn't Android support the standard XML way of doing it? (&apos;)

Comment: @Cristian — I did read the documentation, the XML documentation. The android developers appear not to have done :) (And the Android docs say that `&apos;` won't work)

Comment: Really? I didn't read the documentation to test `&apos;`. Instead I wrote a little app to test and it worked :)

Comment: Considering that it is very central in XML it would be quite bad if they created a parser without support for it. I don't think I would have called it xml if it lacked support for it.

Answer (score 7):

```
<string name="good_example">"This'll work"</string>
<string name="good_example_2">This\'ll also work</string>
```

Taken from the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html